# JMeter Ant Task doesn't works for Distributed Testing

Tags: ant, jmeter

When I tried to execute Distributed Testing using JMeter Ant Task,it's not running. I have configured remote_hosts in the jmeterproperties file. When I looked at eth Jmeter ant Task document it says runremote set to true, but I am not sure where do I need to specify that and what am I missing could you please advise!

Below are the build. xml and Test execution output screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the "runremote" property for the Jmeter task in ANT as given below.

```
<jmeter
   jmeterhome="c:\jakarta-jmeter-1.8.1"
   testplan="${basedir}/loadtests/JMeterLoadTest.jmx"
   resultlog="${basedir}/loadtests/JMeterResults.jtl"
   runremote="true">
   <property name="request.threads" value="1"/>
   <property name="request.loop" value="10"/>
</jmeter>
```

Currently you are passing this as a property to the JMeter test which is not right.

Comment: I got it Thank You Vinoth!